# VS C# Tracking Objects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Does Visual Studio 2015 has a debug window where we can track what objects are being GC or destroyed and what objects are still referenced, regardless of the object scope?

(tracking at App domain level all objects created in code excluding the .NET ones)

Comment: No, and I don't see such a thing as being useful.

Comment: if your trying to track down a memory leak you might as well use a free tool

Comment: I'd recommend looking into WinDbg and Son of Strike (SOS) extension for these types of things.